# FB Message Dialog "invite friends" feature using Xamarin

Tags: ios, facebook, xamarin, facebook-ios-sdk

In v2.0 of the Facebook Graph API the only way to allow a user to invite his Facebook friends to an app is to use the [Message Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/share#message-dialog). The Message Dialog makes a one-line call to the FB sdk and does an app switch to the native **Facebook Messenger** app where the user can send a message and invite his friends to try out the app.

Is there a way to use this feature on Xamarin iOS?